# Click area sensitivity

Tags: jquery, mouse, mousedown, mouseup, jqueryi-ui-buttonset

I'm speaking broadly here -- you know how when you click a button, for example one in a set of styled radio buttons, and if you accidentally drag the cursor even one pixel while in the down state, the release state does not trigger your event because it thinks you were maybe trying to drag / select text or something other than a click...

This sucks.

Is there a way to address this, in my view, *over* sensitivity?

I'm using jquery buttonset and I find I have to click VERY deliberately, without moving a single pixel in between down and up states in order for the click to work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `click` have you tried with `mousedown`?

a `click` needs both up and down, while `mousedown` needs only a down

Comment: The problem is that I'm using jquery ui and I can't find click anywhere in the buttonset code block to change it to onPress  (mousedown)...